# Cacti does not show graphs

Tags: apache-http-server, monitoring

I installed [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) on my Linux - Apache2 for monitoring purposes but it does not show graph PNG files!

Has anyone face this problem before?

- I looked over logs, no alerts there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set it up correctly? What have you done to configure it? It will not "work" out of the box (if by "work" you mean spit out ready graphs of network usage). It is quite convoluted to do this the first time and might take some time.

Try enabling some of the simplest available data series with as few dependencies as possible (usually the ones containing logged in users, memory status, etc.) to see if you can get any output at all.

There is a graph preview mode in the admin interface — if you don't manage to get visible graphs there, then you should concentrate on that. Read up on general how-tos on the subject.

If it is just the network graphs that are troublesome, the first step is to add an "Associated data query" in Console → Devices corresponding to your machine. Try to go from there and figure out the system.

If graphs show up in this preview mode but are not generated to files, check permissions on the target directory. Though Cacti should log any errors, so maybe you are just not generating them at all. This is handled via Configuration → Settings → Graph export.